# How does "validator" javascript trojan effect my PC?

Tags: javascript, virus, trojan

My Kaspersky Internet Security said it just blocked a `HEUR:Trojan.Script.Generic` from this web page (Do not go to the web page below, it may damage your PC):

```
https://trafficvalidator.com/launch/validatorsrc.min.js
```

First thing first, can I ask what's the trojan above? how can I tell if it has effected my PC? Also I think that's weird because the trojan actually comes from a `https` web page, normally, I think `https` webpage is safe.

Secondly, How does "validator" javascript trojan effect my PC (what can it do)? So if I install an exe to my PC, that contains trojan, then it makes sense cause it has administrator's right and it can change my PC. but I don't understand what a Javascript trojan can do, but if it can really do something bad to my PC, is it a bad idea to enable Javascript for my browser?

Note: I call it "validator" javascript trojan because it comes from the script `validatorsrc.min.js`

Comment: Think of `https` as standing in your house and `http` standing in public. You're safe in your house from people pickpocketing your belongings, but you can still be physically attacked by a man who targets your house (or houses).

`https` secures the channel, not what's on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HEUR indicates that Kaspersky uses heuristics to determine that this script might have "unusual" or "malicious" behavior.  At a quick glance, the script doesn't actually appear to be malicious per se, but does seem to be an in-browser cryptocoin miner.  This is a [widely reported phenomenon](https://www.coindesk.com/coinhive-cryptocurrency-miner-is-6th-most-common-malware-says-report/) and "only" uses your browser to mine coins while you are on the site.  It does not appear to steal any data, persist itself, or damage your computer in any way.  (Again, this is just from a quick glance and I haven't done a full reverse engineering of the payload.)

As to the `https` protocol in use: anyone can obtain a certificate for a domain they control.  `https` protects your connection to that server, but says nothing about the trustworthiness or security of the server itself.